# Taking time to remove a record after deleting in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I have written code to delete a record (Just changing the status of the record from 1 to 0).  Delete is working fine.

But the problem is, after deleting the record, it's not deleting immediately after I click on refresh button. it's removing the record from the list.  This is the code which I have written for that.

Controller:

```
function index()
{    
 $data['records'] = $this->career_model->get_jobs_list();
 $data['mainpage']='career';
 $data['mode']='all';
 $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
 }
function delete()                   
{    

     $this->career_model->delete($this->uri->segment(3));                    
     $this->flash->success('<h2>Successfully deleted the record.<h2>');
     redirect('careers');                   
}
```

Model:

```
function get_jobs_list()
{
    $this->db->Select('jobs_list.*');
    $this->db->From('jobs_list');
    $this->db->where(array('jobs_list.status'=>1));
    $q=$this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)      
    {       
        return $q->result();
     }
        else
        {
    return false;
  }
}
function delete($jobs_id)
{
    $data=array('status'=>0);
    $this->db->where(array('jobs_id'=>$jobs_id));
    $this->db->update('jobs_list',$data);
}
```

View:

```
<div id="mydiv">    
        <?php    echo $this->flash->display('success', TRUE);?>
    </div>
    <script> 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#mydiv').hide('fast');
        }, 10000);
    </script>

    <div id="main">         
        <div class="full_w">
            <div class="h_title">
                <div class="lefttitle fl">
                    Categories
                </div>
                <div class="rightbutton fr">
                    <a class="button add" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/careers/add">Add </a>
                    <a class="button del" href="<?php echo site_url()?>/careers/deactivated">Deactivated </a>                       
                </div>
            </div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">S.No</th>
                        <th scope="col">Job List</th>                           
                        <th scope="col" style="width: 65px;">Modify</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <?php if(isset($records) && is_array($records) && count($records)>0): ?>    
                <?php  $i=0;foreach($records as $r):$i++;?>     
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-center"><?php echo $i;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $r->job_name;?></td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/careers/edit/<?php echo $r ->jobs_id ;?>" class="table-icon edit" title="Edit"></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/careers/delete/<?php echo $r ->jobs_id ;?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete');" class="table-icon delete" title="Delete"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach ;endif;?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: try redirect('careers', 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

try `redirect('/careers', 'refresh');`

from the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect)

> The optional second parameter allows you to force a particular
>   redirection method. The available methods are auto, location and
>   refresh, with location being faster but less reliable on IIS servers.
>   The default is auto, which will attempt to intelligently choose the
>   method based on the server environment.

Comment: how is the route of 'careers'?

Comment: i am not getting you which route

Comment: careers is a controller or a view?

Comment: Its a controller

Comment: what about redirect('/careers', 'refresh');

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding single quote in the model `get_jobs_list()` function.

change `$this->db->where(array('jobs_list.status'=>1));` to `$this->db->where(array('jobs_list.status'=>'1'));`